# Entity framework 4 - Adding a object without Identity column throws OptimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database first approach, using EF4 on Sybase.

SSDL

```
    <EntityType Name="tq_qmt_logger">
    <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="qmt_id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="qmt_id" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"  />
    <Property Name="client_id" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
    <Property Name="logged_date" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" />
```

CSDL

I have corresponding CSDL with annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"

Now my source code is,

```
            tq_qmt_logger qmtLogger = new tq_qmt_logger();
            qmtLogger.client_id = machineID;
            qmtLogger.logged_date = DateTime.Now;

            // qmtlogger.qmt id is omitted because it is
            // generated by a sequence in the DB.

            context.tq_qmt_logger.AddObject(qmtLogger);
            context.savechanges()
```

SaveChanges throws OptimisticConcurrencyException with error Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). My guess is, EF passes 0 to my qmt_id (identity) column, which is getting rejected. Can someone guide how to fix this?

Comment: You're using a four-year-old version of EF. If you can't be bothered to stay even barely current you're not going to find answers to your problems.

Comment: I work in a legacy application with 9 million lines of code and 4 million customers who are even using the application in XP.  We have to support .NET Framework 4.0.  Hence we are in EF4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: has your db autoincrement on qmt_id column? if not, EF won't pass it as a parameter because it thinks it will be provided by DBMS, and DBMS will have problem with not provided ID value.